# Navigation with toolbar up arrow restarts the app but android built-in arrow button works

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Please assist.

*Edited to ask a more simple straight forward questions*

I have three activities (A, B and C) that each host a fragment.
Navigation with up arrow on toolbar is not working when navigating from fragment C to fragment B. However, navigation with the built-in android back arrow, works fine.

Comparing the logging of the lifecycle methods below with the two different back navigations, why does it get destroyed, detached and recreated (where it crashes and restarts the app because the arguments bundle is empty) with the toolbar back navigation, but goes straight from stop to start on the built-in android back navigation?

**Order of activity and fragment lifecycle on toolbar up arrow**

```
11-30 19:41:15.491 2070-2086/? I/PgedBinderListener: kstate callback type:16 value1=1433 value2=CALLED
11-30 19:41:15.537 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onCreate Called
11-30 19:41:15.541 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onCreateView Called
11-30 19:41:15.607 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onDestroyView Called
11-30 19:41:15.607 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onStart Called
11-30 19:41:15.607 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onStart() called
11-30 19:41:15.607 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onResume() called
11-30 19:41:15.607 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onResume Called
11-30 19:41:17.321 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onPause() called
11-30 19:41:17.878 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onStopCalled
11-30 19:41:17.878 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onStop() called
11-30 19:41:18.838 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onDestroyView Called
11-30 19:41:18.839 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onDestroy Called
11-30 19:41:18.839 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onDetached Called
11-30 19:41:18.839 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onDestroy() called
11-30 19:41:18.874 13374-13374/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onCreate Called
```

**Order of activity and fragment lifecycle with android built-in back arrow**

```
12-02 22:31:10.355 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onCreate Called
12-02 22:31:10.357 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onCreateView Called
12-02 22:31:10.420 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onDestroyView Called
12-02 22:31:10.420 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onStart Called
12-02 22:31:10.420 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onStart() called
12-02 22:31:10.421 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onResume() called
12-02 22:31:10.421 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onResume Called
12-02 22:31:13.499 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onPause() called
12-02 22:31:14.122 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onStopCalled
12-02 22:31:14.122 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onStop() called
12-02 22:31:27.380 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onStart Called
12-02 22:31:27.380 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onStart() called
12-02 22:31:27.380 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/child_details_activity: onResume() called
12-02 22:31:27.380 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook I/ChildDetailsFragment: onResume Called
```

**Abstract class for hosting activities**

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }


}
```

**Activity B**

```
public class ChildDetailsActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_CHILD_ID =
            "com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook.child_id";
    public static final String TAG = "child_details_activity";

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packagedContext, UUID childId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packagedContext, ChildDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CHILD_ID, childId);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        UUID childId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CHILD_ID);
        return ChildDetailsFragment.newInstance(childId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume() called");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        String  uuid = getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CHILD_ID).toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop() called" + uuid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
    }
}
```

**Fragment B**

```
public class ChildDetailsFragment extends Fragment{


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private Child mChild;

    private static final String ARGS_ID = "child_id";
    private static final String SAVED_INSTANCE_STATE_UUID = "clinicbook.childdetailsfragment.mchildid";



    public static ChildDetailsFragment newInstance(UUID childId) {
        ChildDetailsFragment childDetailsFragment = new ChildDetailsFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARGS_ID, childId);

        childDetailsFragment.setArguments(args);
        return childDetailsFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("ChildDetailsFragment", "onCreate Called");
        ChildList childList = ChildList.getChildList(getActivity());
        UUID childId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARGS_ID);
        mChild = childList.getChild(childId);
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child_details, container, false);

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mChild.getFirstName() + " " + mChild.getLastName());

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.child_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter());

        return  v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("ChildDetailsFragment", "onDestroy Called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("ChildDetailsFragment", "fragment onStopCalled");
    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //RecyclerView ViewHolder

    private class CategoryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public CategoryHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, parent, false));
            ((LinearLayout) itemView).setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bind(String category) {
            TextView categoryTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
            categoryTitle.setText(category);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PersonalDataActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    //RecyclerView ViewHolder
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //RecyclerView Adapter

    private class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryHolder> {

        private final String[] mCategoryList = {
                "Personal Data",
                "Growth Measurements",
                "Growth Stages",
                "Immunisations",
                "Medications",
                "Allergies"
        };

        @Override
        public CategoryHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            return new CategoryHolder(inflater, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryHolder holder, int position) {
            String category = mCategoryList[position];
            holder.bind(category);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCategoryList.length;
        }
    }
    //RecyclerView Adapter
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}// End of Class ChildDetailsFragment
```

**Activity C**

```
public class PersonalDataActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new PersonalDataFragment();
    }
}
```

**Fragment C**
    public class PersonalDataFragment extends Fragment {

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal_data, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".ChildrenActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ChildDetailsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ChildrenActivity">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".PersonalDataActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ChildDetailsActivity">
</activity>
```

**Stack Trace fatal error is as follows:**

```
12-02 22:42:18.330 16037-16037/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook, PID: 16037
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook/com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook.ChildDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.UUID.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2479)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5659)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.UUID.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook.ChildList.getChild(ChildList.java:67)
                                                                                    at com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook.ChildDetailsFragment.onCreate(ChildDetailsFragment.java:50)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1109)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:996)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:99)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2364)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3221)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3171)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:560)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                                    at com.navsaria.keeran.clinicbook.ChildDetailsActivity.onStart(ChildDetailsActivity.java:56)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1241)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6392)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5659) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
```

Test Device is Huawei P9 lite

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Change the launchMode of ChildDetailsActivity in the AndroidManifest to "singleTop" so that the activity in the back stack receives the intent instead of a new activity being created.

```
<activity android:name=".ChildDetailsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ChildrenActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```